# unable to find a version of 'run_loop' to activate (Gem::LoadError)

Tags: ruby, rubygems, cucumber, calabash, calabash-ios

I am getting below mentioned error in Calabash-IOS during execute any cucumber command for executing feature file.

> unable to find a version of 'run_loop' to activate (Gem::LoadError)

I am using gem versions which is given below-

```
command_runner_ng (0.1.0)
cucumber (2.4.0, 1.3.20)
cucumber-core (1.5.0)
cucumber-wire (0.0.1)

calabash-cucumber (0.19.2, 0.12.3)
```

Thanks

Comment: Add [`run_loop`](https://github.com/calabash/run_loop) to your `Gemfile`.

Answer (score 2):

This is because of multiple versions of cucumber. Uninstall the cucumber and reinstall again solves the problem.

$ gem uninstall cucumber

$ gem install cucumber

Answer (score 0):

Running `gem dependency --remote calabash-cucumber` shows a fairly extensive list of dependencies:

```
Gem calabash-cucumber-0.19.2:
  awesome_print (>= 0)
  bundler (~> 1.3)
  clipboard (~> 1.0)
  cucumber (>= 0)
  edn (< 2.0, >= 1.0.6)
  geocoder (< 2.0, >= 1.1.8)
  growl (>= 0, development)
  guard-bundler (>= 0, development)
  guard-rspec (>= 0, development)
  httpclient (< 3.0, >= 2.3.2)
  json (>= 0)
  listen (= 3.0.6, development)
  luffa (>= 1.1.0, development)
  oj (~> 2.0, development)
  pry (>= 0, development)
  pry-nav (>= 0, development)
  rake (= 10.5.0, development)
  redcarpet (= 3.2.0, development)
  rspec (>= 0, development)
  rspec_junit_formatter (>= 0, development)
  run_loop (< 3.0, >= 2.1.3)
  slowhandcuke (~> 0.0.3)
  stub_env (>= 0, development)
  yard (~> 0.8, development)
```

Fourth from the bottom, it seems run_loop needs to be at least 2.1.3 and less than 3.0 for the version of calabash-cucumber you're using. I would suggest that you start by verifying that an appropriate version is installed. Try running:

```
gem list run_loop
```

If the version installed is within the listed version range, then it's possible one of the other gems you're using (including a dependency of a gem) might have different or more specific requirements. I don't know of a great way to check that automatically (short of writing a short Ruby program to do some creative grepping), but poking around at the main gems you're requiring is reasonably likely to uncover the issue.